# HTML centering navbar with an image/video

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is a bad question, I am very new to website development.

I am having a bit of trouble centering my navbar to the rest of the page. I have messed around with it quite a bit but for some reason, I can't get it to be centered with the text. It is just so slightly off. I have provided an image as well as my code. I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look and give me any tips or advice.

https://nathanscottcreations.github.io/

```css
  #wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)), ` url(mountain.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
}

a:link {
  color: #414141
}

a:hover {
  color: #ebc600;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local("Lato Light Italic"), local("Lato-LightItalic"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ubuntucondensed/v8/u- 
 4k0rCzjgs5J7oXnJcM_0kACGMtT-Dfqw.woff2) format("woff2");
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccad14 10%, #fff 50%, #262626 80%);
  background-size: auto auto;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: #fff;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: textclip 1.35s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes textclip {
  to {
    background-position: 200% center;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Valley City Group</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="VCGstyle.css">


</head>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><video onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause();this.currentTime=0;" style="width: 
        175px; height: 175px;">;
   <source id="mp4" src="animatedLOGO.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video></li>
    <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <h1>Valley City Group</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>About Us</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also, I have found out that the video is not centered in the middle flex box. Working on that now.

Answer (score 0):

CSS for header

```
width:100%;
text-align:center;
```

CSS for your img

```
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I already have the css for the header <h1> included. I placed your other css n the <li> section. I have updated the website link but it still looks a little off. I have grayed the background so it is easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

My CSS solution:

```
    *           {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                }

    nav ul      {
                text-align: center;
                }

    nav ul li   {
                display: inline-block;
                color: white;
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 1%;
                padding-left: 4%;
                padding-right: 4%;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 22px;
                }

    nav ul li a {
                color: black;
                list-style-type: none;
                text-decoration:none;
                }
```

Along with my HTML:

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><video onmouseover="this.play()" 
         onmouseout="this.pause();this.currentTime=0;">;
        <source id="mp4" src="logo2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```